QPushButton:hover not taken into account
I have read many questions/ answers on this topic but I still can't get the hover background to apply.
The default background color of QPushButton is working and when the mouse Gets over the button the color changes to white (but I haven't specified it).
Whatever the hover background color I specify, it seems that another behaviour is taking over and I cannot specify something else.
I am on Windows 11 and I use QtCreator.
This is very annoying since the default hover color (which I do not succeed to change) is tightly closed to the normal color I want to use.
I'm getting a lot frustrated because on all posts I read correcting the style-sheet was enough but it doesn't work for me...
Any idea where that default hover background is specified or why I can't modify it ?
Is this because of the Windows style (which applies by default and which has many great features) ?
It seems strange to me that normal backgrounds can be changed but not the hover ones...
The stylesheet to reproduce the problem is simply:
QPushButton { background: red }
QPushButton:hover { background: blue }


Please provide a [mre], also include the specific Qt version you're using and the objectName() of the QApplication::style() (before setting any stylesheets, if you're using QApplication::setStyleSheet()). Note that if you can reproduce the issue even with the button being the top level widget (or the only widget in a window), it's enough to include the QSS contents.

It does not really require a MRE... A simple widget created in the designer with only a QPushButton in it and previewed in default (as per the question, on Windows)/windows11 styles does reproduce the problem, even though other styles (windows/windowsvista/fusion) work well (that answers one of the questions BTW). As for the QSS, it is as simple as it can get; I've edited the question to add it.

@Atmo I suspected that, but since I cannot test reliably on modern Windows (and the new Windows11 theme already has shown issues), I couldn't be sure. In any case, that's expected for pixmap bases themes. (Note that we should avoid to update other's posts by altering/adding code on our own: even if this may be a "valid case", it's always better to leave that to the OP)
